# Virtual function in Inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual, pure-virtual, run-time-polymorphism

**Read the below mention code **

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class FR
{
public :
    virtual int fun() 
    {
      cout<<"In FR Class "<<endl;
    }

    int Threading()
    {
        fun();
    }
};

class FD : public FR
{
public :
    int fun()
    {
        cout<<" In FD class "<<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    FD obj ;

    obj.Threading();
}
```

Here,output of this is "in FD class".

here we have inheritance the FR class into FD class,so all property from the FR class is inheritade from the based class,
but when we call the `Threading()` function using the FD object than it will called the based class but for Threading class `Fun()` function is available as virtual and Fun definition is also available so
why it not classed the based class `Fun()` function.

I'm expecting that when we called the `Threading()` function than it should be called the class FR `Fun()` function not class FD `Fun()`.

Actual OutPut   : "In FD Class"

Expected OutPut : "In FR Class"

Comment: `obj` is an `FD` hence calling the method `fun` calls `FD::fun` thats what virtual is all about

Comment: what your code does is known as the [Template Method Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

Comment: Your expectation is based on not fully understanding what `virtual` does. Read that chapter again.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number the GOF definition of template is at odds with the C++ definition.

Comment: @MarkRansom yes the name is unfortunate, thats why I always link an article when mentioning it.

Comment: Remove the keyword `virtual` from your code and you will get the output you are expecting.  Your actual output is the result of `virtual` doing exactly what it is supposed to do.

Answer (score 3):

This is known as virtual dispatch and is basically just what `virtual` means not more. The method to be called is determined by the dynamic type of the object.

You can think of the call as having a `this->`:

```
class FR
{
public :
    virtual int fun() 
    {
      cout<<"In FR Class "<<endl;
    }

    int Threading()
    {
        this->fun();
    }
};
```

When `Threading` is called on an object of type `FD` then in above code `this` is a `FR*` but the dynamic type of the object to which `this` points is `FD`. Hence when the virtual `fun()` is called it calls `FD::fun()`.

If you do not want virtual dispatch for `fun` remove the `virtual`. Then your code will print "In FR Class".

Answer (score 3):

Virtual functions are called through the table of virtual function pointers.

The derived class FD overwrites the address of the virtual function fun with the address of its own overriding function in its tangle of virtual function pointers.

So in this sequence of calls

```
obj.Threading();
```

and

```
int Threading()
{
    fun();
}
```

to call the function fun the pointer to the function fun is searched in the table of virtual function pointers of the class FD and correspondingly the function definition provided in the class FD is used.
then the o

Comment: the vtable is an implementation detail. OPs code would produce same output also when there was no vtable

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number But under the hood nevertheless there is used the described logic.

Comment: yes, its an implementation detail ;).

Comment: The C++ standard does not specify that you must use a vtable. It might be good to know about since it's so widely used, but it's a mistake to assume that's the only way virtual methods could be done.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a method as virtual, a vtable will be generated for that class (if it is concrete, i.e. has no pure virtual members) that contains pointers to each of the virtual functions in the class. A vtable will also be generated for every class that derives from the class with the virtual method (as long as they are also concrete).

Each object of the class then gets a vtable pointer that points to their particular vtable. Your class `FR` has a pointer to the vtable containing `FR::fun`, whereas your class `FD` has a pointer to the vtable containing `FD::fun`.

Since `Threading` is non-virtual, when `Threading` is called on an object of class `FD`, the method implemented in `FR` is called with a `this` pointer to the `FD` object. Then, when `Threading` calls `this->fun` it looks for the function in the `FD`'s vtable and calls `FD::fun`.

Comment: the vtable is an implementation detail. OPs code would produce same output also when there was no vtable.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I'm not sure that this is correct, the `this` pointer passed to `FR::Threading` is of type `FR*`. To call `fun` on a pointer to an `FR` and get to a function implemented in `FD` surely you have to go through the vtable?

Comment: what I mean is that the c++ standard does not mention the vtable, it merely specifies what happens when you call a virtual method. Consider eg that there is devirtualization (https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2021/02/15/devirtualization/), where no lookup must be made, because its all known at compile time already, also in such cases virtual methods work as they should.

Comment: I'm not sure that any of those examples exactly match this case. However, if the OP was only interested in exactly what the standard says they would have tagged the post as language lawyer. Since the vtable is the way in which every compiler implements virtual dispatch in practically every useful case, and the OP does not have a full understanding of what the virtual keyword means, it is useful information for them to know about the vtable and how it would actually work in this case.

Comment: yes it is useful information. Though one should not put the cart before the horse, hence I think it is also useful to add that the virtual table is just an implementation detail